# Relation between LinkDistance and LinkStrength in D3.js Force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph-layout, force-layout

How are the LinkDistance and LinkStrength related in a force directed layout in D3.js? I am assuming that they are, correct me if i am wrong.

I understand that the linkDistance defines the length between any pair of nodes and essentially serves as constraint in a force layout. But what role does linkStrength play? The API documentation for D3.js defines it as the "strength (rigidity) of links to the specified value in the range [0,1]" What does "rigidity" mean here exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the link distance as the expected distance and the strength as the speed at which you want to reach this target distance on each iteration.

---

If you have a look at the [source code of the force directed layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js), you will find the following line:

```
l = alpha * strengths[i] * ((l = Math.sqrt(l)) - distances[i]) / l;
```

This algorithm is an optimization algorithm, thus, on each iteration you modify `l`. Now the thing is that you have to specify by how much you modify this.

On a basic algorithm you would have the following in order to optimize the distances:

```
l = ((l = Math.sqrt(l)) - distances[i]) / l;
```

However you might want to have more control on every links and also on each individual link. Hence, you can consider the `alpha` attribute as the fixed parameter and the `strength` attribute as the parameter that varies for each link.

If you want to know more about the optimization method used, I recommend you to have a look at the [Gauss-Seidel wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method).

Comment: thanks for your answer! is this alpha by any chance the cooling parameter as provided in the API of the force layout, D3.js?

Comment: Exactly! I really recommend you to have a look at the source code to know more about how it actually works.